# how to set a field in mysql when loading a page using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I need to set a variable in a person's profile when they hit a page, so that if they refresh or try and click the link again, the page will not load a video.  I can get most of this done, but I can't seem to find a reliable way to set a 'video' field to 1 when the page simply loads. The default variable is 0 for every user and when they load the page, it should set this 'video' field to 1.

I tried this but getting an error:

```
$video = "query_to_find_video_field";
if ($video==0) {
$sql = "UPDATE profile set video=1 Where id='.$user->id"; 
$query = mysql_query($sql);
}
```

So as you can see, it would only execute that SQL query if the field was not previously set. Thanks!

Comment: and that error would be?

Comment: For one, you have a `'` in your query but never close it.  What's with the `.`? Did you mean to do `"UPDATE profile set video=1 Where id=" . $user->id;` ?

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user data is **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and can be exploited.

Comment: Where is `$user->id` coming from? Is that some sort of User class that's an actual ORM?

Comment: Assuming that you are fine with $user->id just change your update query to: $sql = "UPDATE profile set video=1 Where id=".$user->id;

Comment: I'm using PHP7 which is probably the problem.  Any help with PDO? deadline tomorrow!  thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Stop using `mysql`. It has been deprecated from php. I'll recommend you to learn `PDO` or `bind param`.

Try this for now:

```
$video = "query_to_find_video_field";
if ($video==0) { 
$sql = "UPDATE profile set video=1 Where id='$user->id'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I get this error: "Call to undefined function mysql_query()"